# In a $v$-vertex red/blue edge-colored graph $G$, is $c(G_{\mathrm{red}})+c(G_{\mathrm{blue}}) \leq c(G)+v$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple $v$-vertex graph.  Suppose $G$ has its edges colored either red or blue (the coloring might not be proper).

Let $G_{\mathrm{red}}$ denote the subgraph of $G$ formed by the red edges, and $G_{\mathrm{blue}}$ denote the subgraph of $G$ formed by the blue edges.  Let $c(\cdots)$ denote the number of components in a graph.

> *Question*:  Do we have $$c(G_{\mathrm{red}})+c(G_{\mathrm{blue}}) \leq c(G)+v?$$

Equality occurs when all the edges are red (or blue).

At this point, I'm not sure the bound is even true, but it seems like if we change edges in the all-red coloring, it makes the left-hand side smaller.

An attempt at proving this would be to assume we have a coloring that achieves the maximum, and turn the blue edges red one-by-one (or component-by-component), while verifying that we have not decreased $c(G_{\mathrm{red}})+c(G_{\mathrm{blue}})$, until we get all edges colored red.  This doesn't seem to work, however: if we naively take a blue edge and change it red, we may decrease $c(G_{\mathrm{red}})$ by $1$ without increasing $c(G_{\mathrm{blue}})$.  We could do this switch if there were a cycle with a single blue edge in it, as this wouldn't decrease $c(G_{\mathrm{red}})$.  But such a cycle might not exist.

(This is related to a research problem I'm working on; it's a more complicated version of this problem, which I'm a bit frustrated with at the moment (and it also might not be true).  I'm hoping an answer to this question will help me resolve the research problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that induction on the number of edges would work.

For a graph with zero edges the inequality (equality in that case) clearly holds.

Then for any given colored graph, after leaving a (say red) edge $uv$ connecting the vertices $u$ and $v$, the inequality holds by induction. Putting back the removed edge cannot increase the number of components in $G$ or any of it's subgraphs, so the only possible problem would be the left side remaining unchanged with the right side decreasing at the same time.

But if $u$ and $v$ were in separate components in $G$ after leaving $uv$, they must have been in separate components in any subgraph of $G$ as well. Specially, $c(G_{red})$ must decrease as well when putting back $uv$, and thus the inequality will still hold.

I hope that what I'm saying is clear, and that I didn't overlook any problems/details.

Comment: Thanks!  That's clear to me.